# powershell runspace: access to global variable Yes , or no?

Tags: powershell, runspace

I have this module that I import on the local system.   When I run a script block using runspace on the local system as well , the function in that module are accessible in the runspace script block.

This module creates global variables.   I tested if these global variables are also accessible  from the script block running in run space.    They all get returned by get-variable -scope global -name 
But then when I try to access these global from the script block , only some come through.

I could deal with this if all would not show up , or they all would show up.   But that they all show up as being present , but then only some come threw as having content.

The goal is to have this module work in both contexts , local system and local system running in runspace.

Answer (score 1):

In short, everything you want to see in your runspace should be passed into it.

If your values are `ValueType`, you should pass them by reference explicitly. Otherwise, you should pass them as-is (by reference is default for reverence types).

Here is my templete for parallel processing of finite list of items using `PoshRSJob` module and custom `SomeFunction`:

```
Function SomeFunction
{
    Param(
       [String]$SampleParam
    )
    return $SampleParam.ToUpper()
}

$JobScript = [scriptblock]{
    $inQueue = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[string]]$args[0]
    $outBag = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]]$args[1]
    $currentItem = $null
    while($inQueue.TryDequeue([ref] $currentItem) -eq $true)
    {
        try
        {
            # Add result to OutBag
            $result = SomeFunction -SampleParam $currentItem -EA Stop
            $outBag.Add( $result )
        }
        catch
        {
            # Catch error
            Write-Output $_.Exception.ToString()
        }
    }
}

$inData = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentQueue[string]]::new(
    [String[]](@(1..10000) | % { return [guid]::NewGuid().ToString() }) # Sample strings in lower case
    )

$resultData = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[string]]::new()

# Wait for queue to empty
$i_cur = $inData.Count
$i_max = $i_cur

# Start jobs
$jobs = @(1..20) | % { Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock $JobScript -ArgumentList @($inData, $resultData) -FunctionsToImport @('SomeFunction') }

# Wait queue to empty
while($i_cur -gt 0)
{
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Doing job' -Status "$($i_cur) left of $($i_max)" -PercentComplete (100 - ($i_cur / $i_max * 100)) 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 3 # Update frequency
    $i_cur = $inData.Count
}

# Wait jobs to complete
$logs = $jobs | % { Wait-RSJob -Job $_ } | % { Receive-RSJob -Job $_  } 
$jobs | % { Remove-RSJob -Job $_ }
$Global:resultData = $resultData
$Global:logs = $logs
```

Comment: By why do the variables already show up ?  all the 5 global  variables from my module will show up when get-variable -scope 'global' -name '<name of my global ' from the script block.

Comment: I think it's not. `$Global:AAR='YAY!';
Get-Variable -Scope 'Global' | 
    % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | 
    Sort-Object -Property Name |
    ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | 
    Out-File -FilePath 'S:\OutVarsOutsideJob.json.txt'  -Confirm:$false -Force;
Start-Job -Name TestSync -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Variable -Scope 'Global' | 
        % { "$($_.Name)=$($_.Value)" } | 
        Sort-Object -Property Name |
        ConvertTo-Json -Depth 20 | 
        Out-File -FilePath 'S:\OutVarsInsideJob.json.txt' -Confirm:$false -Force
}  | Out-Null;
Get-Job -Name TestSync | Wait-Job | Remove-Job